# Ignore properties before calling savechanges()

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

When I update a record I want to ignore the `CreatedBy` and `CreatedDate` fields from being saved.

I tried setting `IsModfied` to `false` in the repository, but after I call `SaveChanges`() it throws an exception saying the `CreatedBy` field is a required field.

```
public void Save(Company company)
    {
        if (company.CompanyId > 0)
        {
            _context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.Entry(company).Property(c => c.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
            _context.Entry(company).Property(c => c.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
        }
        else
            _context.Companies.Add(company);

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

These fields are in a `BaseModel`

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStringResource))]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaximumLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStringResource))]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStringResource))]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaximumLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStringResource))]
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to ignore these properties when I call update without having hidden inputs or having to get the original company from the database and mapping it to the viewmodel?

Comment: Do you sometimes need to ignore those properties and other times not?

Comment: Those values are only going to be set when I create a new record.  When I'm updating the record I want those properties to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm open to other solutions, but the way I fixed this is to disable `ValidateOnSaveEnabled` in my `SqlContext` file.  From what I read, EF validates all added and modified entities.  Since I already validate my ViewModels I just disabled this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to ignore these properties when doing updates but you require them for new enteries, I would make those properties virtual in the base. Create 2 classes which inherit the base: one for update and one for new entries. The class for new entries should decorate the properties with Required attribute. The other class for updates, should not.

Comment: It's my domain model that inherits the base model.  My ViewModels for the update don't have a required attribute.  If the CreatedBy and CreatedDate are non nullable in the db then wouldn't my domain models have to match that?

Comment: Sorry I did not know that was your domain model. No I do not think it has to match the database. Your database is enforcing these rules and as long as your application layer achieves that, the db does not care how you achieve it. But now I am curious, so you are duplicating all this logic in the viewmodels again?

Comment: I used code first migrations to create the database, so if I want a field to be non-nullable I have to have the `[Required]` attribute.  My ViewModels do have this same logic, but the VMs only contain the properties I need, so for my update VM they don't even have the createdby properties.  Do you think that's bad practice to do it this way?

Comment: If you know how to start a chat, invite me and we can discuss.

Comment: I can't figure out how to invite you.  Try this link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127457/andrew